# C++ GUI without Frameworks

Tags: c++, user-interface, frameworks

So as far as I understand it, there is no way to have a C++ GUI designer and ship your application as one, standalone executable. All the 3rd party frameworks add their dependencies in form of .dll-s etc., be it MFC, Qt, WTL, wxWidgets, GTK. That leaves me with only one solution - design the GUI for my current application myself using Win32 API. Are my assumptions correct or am I missing something? I've always wondered how uTorrent and some others have managed to do it. Thanks.

Comment: If your goal is explicitly to develop a light-weight executable - you better stick with Win32 API. It's not an awful option at all IMHO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can statically link most of the popular GUI frameworks, including MFC, Qt, ATL/WTL, and wxWidgets. I don't know about GTK, but I assume that you probably can statically link it, too.

Statically linking means that instead of dynamically linking to the library code living in a DLL, you link that code directly into your executable, resulting in a single, standalone EXE file you can ship without any external dependencies.

But of course, those dependencies will still *be* there and they will still bloat the size of your executable, which may be a problem, depending on your deployment mechanism. Also, there's something to be said for programming close to the metal, so using the Win32 API directly is definitely an option. That's going to produce the absolutely smallest, lightest application possible, and probably the fastest, too. In fact, I believe this is precisely what μTorrent does (or at least, it's what they used to do several versions ago).

Comment: thanks, I'm familiar (more or less) with static linking, unfortunately that's not an option in my case, as my current project requires the application to be as light-weighted as possible & fast. I think I'm going to stick with Win32API. Just wanted to make sure there was no easier alternative.

Comment: @astralmaster I've no idea what you mean by that comment. You want to use a framework, but you feel that you can't because it's too heavy! Static linking doesn't make an app slow. Using a framework doesn't make an app slow. Large executables don't make an app slow. You can use GUI frameworks and without having enormous executables.

Comment: @David: You can use *some* GUI frameworks without having enormous executables, like MFC or WTL. You can't use Qt and not have an enormous executable.

Comment: Why this requirement on size? Do you need to store the executable 500 million times on an average hdd? Imagine what features you could implement in the time you save by using a proper framework and just require a tiny bit of more hdd space...

Comment: @Plasma: Lots of applications are distributed online, and not everyone has a high-speed Internet connection. Download times can mean the difference between them downloading, trying, and using your app, or them moving on to do something else. It's not all about hard drive space.

Comment: @David Heffernan Because the application I was developing, was meant to be run on a device with 256 KB of memory. :)

Comment: 256 KB of memory won't even run Windows, so targeting the Windows API is fairly pointless. Perhaps you mean 256 *MB*?

Answer (score 1):

Some frameworks allow you to build a self-sufficient "standalone monolyte" EXE, without any extra dependencies (apart from obvious API provided by the OS).
For instance in MFC you have an option to either "static" or "dynamic" MFC usage. The 1st option means all the needed stuff will be linked within your EXE.

Comment: thanks for replying. I am sure you agree that MFC is a pain to work with. So there are no other options?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your application's minimal OS requirements, you can link dynamically to an MFC or ATL (in case of a WTL application) version that's included in the minimal targetted version of Windows.

And there's an added advantage of such solution - whenever a security update of the used library comes out, you don't have to update your application in order to benefit from it.

But still it's not that horrible to code for pure Windows API anyway so I'd suggest you go with it.

One problem is that apps compiled with newer versions of Visual Studio require latest CRT runtime library that you have to ship in the installer or make the user install it by himself. There are ways to overcome that. I think [that blog entry](http://kobyk.wordpress.com/2007/07/20/dynamically-linking-with-msvcrtdll-using-visual-c-2005/) is the one I stumbled upon some time ago. Of course you have to be careful with that as if you link dynamically against an old CRT library, it'd be best to code against its headers as well. Maybe there's a way to get rid of the CRT dependency completely.

### Edit

I decided to elaborate after a heated discussion with Cody Gray below to maybe restate my points and put out some warnings.

**Rant incoming**

Even desktop software is a service you have to maintain for the user once you ship it. Operating systems versions change, their APIs and shipped libraries change as well. Apple doesn't have a problem with "breaking" apps with newer OS X and iOS versions and developers understand they have to keep their products up-to-date or they'll lose clients or be too busy with support calls. Microsoft among others in "big business world" created a class of programmers that think of software as buildings. You design it, build it, someone approves it and you're done, after maybe supporting it for two more years. And that's not what it should be.

Even when one writes as much future-proof application as possible, i.e. depending on completely defined, general and documented behavior of the target operating system and any that could come after it, and even they link statically against all libraries it uses, they make it self-contained, correct and *oldnewthing-approved*, they **still** have to actively maintain it for years to come. The libraries it's dependent on do change. They are upgraded, improved, bugs are removed, vulnerabilities are fixed, OS-dependent behavior is updated, removed fixed or generalized.

Even if the app is dependent on the absolutely minimal set of system libraries, everything above applies as well.

So regardless of your app being supposed to be used for a limited time or not, you have to assume and plan **you're going to have to maintain it**, if anything changes that's related to your app. Even if it's a pure Win32 API application, you'll have to check how it behaves in the newer version of Windows, whether it provides UI elements or services that users of that new OS expect from their apps.

And having said that, if you don't go the pure Win32 API route, be mindful of the trade-offs you make *when* and *if* using any of the hacks I originally mentioned.

Even if your project results in a throwaway app. Even if just for future-proofing yourself.

Comment: There are no versions of MFC or ATL that are distributed with Windows, so this is not an option. And the problems created by that blog entry far outnumber the "problems" that it solves...

Comment: I'm quite positive there are MFC and ATL DLLs shipped with Windows. ATL 3.5 and MFC 4.2 I think. Can't find any reliable source though.

Comment: There's a good reason you can't find a reliable source; your information is incorrect. Yes, there are *internal* libraries shipped with Windows for its own use, but the key word there is *internal*: these libraries are not intended for use by applications. You should not rely on them being there. You must still ship the libraries required by your app with your app. [Windows is not an MFC delivery channel.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/01/11/7065021.aspx)

Comment: I'm all for Raymond Chen's preachings and definitely wouldn't depend on some shady Kodak Image Viewer components, but I wouldn't have a problem to depend on MFC 4.2, or at least ATL 3.5 being there. I know that's maybe partially creating the problem Raymond dedicates his blog to - forcing MS to make Windows backward-compatible 20 years back. But hey, I just checked - Windows 8 Consumer Preview ships with those DLLs as well. And if you care about your app the way I can see you do, if anything changes, you'll surely update it.
But main point of my answer stays - go with the Pure. ;)

Comment: Uh, that last comment is the biggest contradiction I've ever read. I'm not even sure how to respond to it... If you think the linked blog post is about Kodak Image Viewer, then you missed the point (and don't look now, but he specifically addresses you at the bottom: *"I now predict that everybody will comment on the last two sentences and completely ignore the point of this article."*). No, relying on MFC 4.2 being there is completely incorrect. It's a private DLL for a reason. It's also not the same as MFC 4.2 that ships with Visual Studio 6; same problem as the CRT.

Comment: Yeah, I got that part, get the point of the post and don't think that it's about Kodak Image Viewer. My point is that MFC 4.2 and ATL 3.5 DLLs are much more depended on than others which had their short time of glory in Windows' system32 folder. They won't be simply removed with the next version of Windows. They'be been there for at least 15 years and it looks like they'll be there for the next 5-10 (see my Windows 8 CP remark). I think even Visual Studio 2005 produced WTL apps that depended on ATL 3.5 DLL. What's that tell you?

Comment: Ah, so you're saying that because other people have committed the sin before in the past, you should be perfectly safe doing it yourself from now on? Yeah, I guess... (No, I completely disagree and think this is really bad advice. Are you *sure* you've read Raymond's blog before?)

Comment: I've been a fan of Raymond's blog for 10 years now. Probably longer that you've been coding at all. I simply stopped being religious about it. If I write an app with previously discussed assumptions and it gets "broken" by Microsoft, I'll update it, because that's completely my responsibility. I'd appreciate a little less condenscention, thanks.

Comment: Yes, everyone thinks it's okay if *they* do it, but no one else does it. That's precisely the problem. Not worth arguing about, I'm clearly not going to change your mind. I'm merely suggesting that you not provide this advice to others who might not understand the drawbacks it entails.

Comment: I understand your anger at the world Raymond's blog portrays because, believe me or not, I used to be *exactly* like this. You're right about the dangerous advice though. If there are guns laying around, someone will eventually get shot, even if it's just their own foot. And OP wants a gun. Answer updated.