# Running .net based exe application without .NET Framework

Tags: c++, .net, clr

I just created a clr c++ aplication that combine c++ code and windows form 
as resoalt the exe prodused from visual studio cannot use /mt and its not standalone (it require the wright .net installed on the computer)

are there ANY way to make a fully standalone exe from clr c++ exe?

i tried to check out spoon studio and Cameyo but it's look like they work only on files that includes instalation ...

Comment: For a .NET application, you are stuck with having to install the right framework, but take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654167/c-gui-without-frameworks

Answer (score 0):

The point is what a standalone application would buy you here? There is no such thing as a "standalone application" anyway - depending on how hard you look at it. You'll always have dependencies at least on the Windows version you intent your application to run on.

In the end it boils down to deployment or distribution issues. If you don't want your users to install a (newer) version of the .NET framework just to run your application, then start by determining the lowest Windows version you want to support with your application. Then check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb822049(v=vs.110).aspx) for the .NET version that comes preinstalled with that version of windows. Then target your application against that version of .NET.